# What is the WinCe event log?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, event-viewer

In the Windows Event Viewer (`Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer`) I find an unusual log called `WinCe Log`. Do not recall seeing this before. The log is full of over 1,500 errors, always with Event ID #1030 or #1058.

What is this log and how to prevent these events from occurring?

[image: WinCe Log]

#### UPDATE

Checking the list against the `Applications` log shows that it contains entries with exactly the same information (eg. `Time` and `Event ID`)...except for a different `Description` (see below)! Furthermore, when checking the properties of the logs, I find the following:

```
Application
Name: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\AppEvent.Evt
Created: 14 March 2008 11:17:28

WinCe Log
Name: C:\WINDOWS\system32
Created: 14 March 2008 11:10:52
```

The name of `WinCe Log` seems incomplete. Following links on the event IDs (for example [this Microsoft TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727265(v=ws.10).aspx) shows that the problem is related to something called `Group Policy`.

Later I found [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/887303) which gives further details and following the trail I found a resolution for the problem. The following services were not running on the computer:

```
DNS Client
TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper
```

Setting these services to start automatically (and rebooting) resulted in the errors going away and being replaced by "Success" messages with event ID 1704.

Now to the `Description` (which different between the logs), taking event ID 1030 as an example:

```
Application
Windows cannot query for the list of Group Policy objects. A message that describes the reason for this was previously logged by the policy engine.

WinCe Log
The description for Event ID ( 1030 ) in Source ( Userenv ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: The event log file is corrupt..
```

So more information...but the questions remain:

- Why is there a WinCe Log?
- Why is it duplicating information contained in the `Application` log?
- Where is it trying (and failing) to get its event description string from?

Comment: This is not a normal log group: it must have been generated by software that you have installed. The entry details may give an indication of the generating program. Check for related names in your installed software list. My XP logs have only the first four groups in your list, as I don't use PowerShell on XP; I have a lot more groups on Win10.

Comment: Curiously, the events in the `WinCe Log` appear to contain ***exactly*** the same entries as the `Application log`. I'll add that information to the question.

Comment: That _is_curious: I don't know the structure of the event log, but I'd guess that the different groups are indexes into the same log using different tags in the messages. Maybe the groups are created automatically as tags are encountered, but this is pure speculation, based on how I might have coded it.